# What will happen if Bitcoin proof of work is not successful in 10 minutes?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin

We know bitcoin block time is 10 min. So in 10 minutes intervals a new block is created with last 10min transactions. What will happen if proof of work is not successful or correct hash generation is not successful within next 10min?
Will the scenario be like no bitcoin will be mined for that 10 min duration and the block will be generated for last 20min transactions?

Answer (score 1):

10 minutes is not accurate, but the average time to generate a block. Approximately every 2 weeks, according to the current average block generation time, the current difficulty of generating a "lucky" hash is determined, so that the average time is about 10 minutes. In any case, the new block includes transactions (not necessarily all) that are pending since the formation of the previous block.

Comment: Not getting the point. How 10min time become average time required to validate a new block. A block is generated with all pending transactions since the last successful block. Is this understanding ok?

Comment: 10 minutes is the time it takes to find the "happy" hash of the new block. Verifying transactions takes significantly less time.

Comment: Finding hash (first 19 zeros) of all pending transactions after previous block using nonce means verification and proof of work is successful. Hece block creation is done. And the miner will get reward of 12.5 bitcoin is my understanding ok?

Comment: In general, yes. But the miner can select not all pending transactions into a block, but only some of them at will - for example, with the highest fee.

Comment: I've some more query to understand this properly - 1) If some transactions are missed to be included in a block. Again new block is created using newer transactions and those transactions are still not included to newer block what will happen to those older pending transactions? 2) Is it not mandatory to add new blocks in 10min interval? 3) Can't we say new bitcoin is mined at 10min interval? 4) one block adding means 6.25 bitcoin mined. Is my understanding correct? 5) If there is no transaction happen in long period of time, there will be no new block and no bitcoin mined. Correct?

Comment: 1) Transactions in the block are selected by the one who creates it. If this is a standard client, then there are some general rules. But, in principle, the miner can do this at will.
2) A new block is added as soon as one of the miners has found a "lucky" hash. It's just that the complexity of finding such a hash is selected by the network so that the block is formed on average in 10 minutes.
3) On average, yes, every 10 minutes new bitcoins are generated in the amount of the block mining fee.

Comment: 4) Yes.
5) Honestly, I don’t remember if mining an empty block is possible. But it seems to me that yes, since initially there were few transactions, but the network had to be saturated with new bitcoins, which is possible only as a result of mining.